# How to solve this Word VBA "can't write file due to permissions" error 5487 while mail merging?

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I'm working in Excel 2016, using VBA. From Excel, I attempt to create some form letters based on the data in the spreadsheet.

```
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

Set appWord = New Word.Application
appWord.Visible = True
appWord.Documents.Open _
    FileName:=appData.MergeFilePath

Set doc = appWord.ActiveDocument
doc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
doc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
    Name:=appData.ClientFilePath, _
    Connection:=kWorkRange, _
    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `" & kWorkRange & "`"
doc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
doc.MailMerge.Execute

'On Error Resume Next
'    doc.saved = True
'    doc.Close
'On Error GoTo 0
doc.saved = True
doc.Close
```

When the above code executes, it fails on the last line (`doc.Close`) with the error "Run-time error '5487': Word cannot complete the save due to a file permission error." Note that I'm not trying to save the file.

Also, the property `saved` reverts to false after the error.

I can work around it by removing the comments and essentially retrying the operation. For some reason, I don't get an error the second time around.

I stopped the code and examined other properties of `doc,` but I don't see anything useful

Do you know how to correct this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `doc.Close SaveChanges:=False` ?

Comment: What are AppData.MergeFilePath  & AppData.ClientFilePath? AFAIK they're not Office VBA code.

Comment: @macropo Those are of my own construction. AppData is a global user-defined type that contains various file names and paths. I should have mentioned that. Anyway, the suggestion by Variatus worked!

Comment: @Variatus I wish you would have posted your comment as an answer because it worked! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably appData.MergeFilePath contains a valid filename & path. Try:

```
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
With wdApp
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
  .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(FileName:=appData.MergeFilePath, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .MailMerge
      .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
      .OpenDataSource Name:=appData.ClientFilePath, Connection:=kWorkRange, _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `" & kWorkRange & "`"
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .Execute
    End With
    .Close False
  End With
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
End With
```